# how to combine a rails app (server code) and a ruby gem (client code) in to a common package?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, directory-structure

I have two packages: a rails 3.2 app (server code) and a ruby gem (client code). They each have standard directory structures for rails app and ruby gems respectively. Since there are common codes which can and should be shared between them,  I'd like to combine them into a single package.

What should the final directory structure look like? I'd love to look at any public projects with such directory layouts.

My codes are in Subversion repositories, so solutions using SCM tricks (like svn:external definitions) to link code from different repos are also acceptable.

Comment: What does "client code" exactly mean? Why can't your Rails app use your gem?

Comment: The "client code" refers to rest api clients. Sharable code are mostly classes and methods for manipulating data objects in various formats.

Answer (score 1):

I would extract common stuff to a gem (e.g. `mything-core`) and make both the client and server depend on that.